# how to move a slideshow to the background?

Tags: css

I just started learning HTML/CSS and I've encountered a problem. On my website (www.seandorsman.nl) I have a nav bar on top with a drop down menu. The menu works fine but it is behind the slideshow I have on the main page.

Is there a way to make the navbar always appear in front of the slideshow?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't according to the rules, and thank you for notifying me. But this question has been resolved, and there have been some examples of code in the answer and comments on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `z-index:` in your stylesheet, so I would make your nav bar a higher z-index than the slideshow. This is basically a hierarchy of where elements lay on top of each other, setting `z-index: 999;` in your css for the navigation bar and drop down should fix your issue.

I would try to show you where exactly to add it but the link you provided does not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the elements are floating, z-index only works on positioned elements right?

Comment: I've corrected the link, should be working now!

Comment: Adding <ul style="z-index: 999;"> to your ul works fine for me when I put the class on in the chrome developer toolkit. Add it to your code and see ;)

Comment: Check here: http://i.imgur.com/PNcqVhl.jpg, also your <ul> is already positioned absolute so z-index works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've just added position:relative; to the stylesheet :
/* Menu CSS */#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:100;

that seemed to do the trick, or do i miss something?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have mentioned, you will want to apply a high `z-index` to the navbar. However, for this to work you will also need to apply `position:relative;`, as `z-index` requires a `position` to be set.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a z-index to your menu items. for example, if your css is like this:

```
#menu li {
    z-index:9999;
}
```

it would take all of the list items and move them to layer 9999. sometimes the position attribute can play into this as well, but I would try modifying the z-index first.

Comment: @SimonStaton you need either `position: relative or absolute` for `z-index` to work. @Hideki you would only need to apply it to the parent, not all the children